# Executing for loop to call Windows application

Tags: vbscript, infinite-loop

I have an existing VBScript which calls an application, then loops if the application exits via user intervention, if a certain user is logged in, otherwise it runs Explorer:

```vb
' Declare variables
dim fso
dim shell
dim oWshNet

set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' get name of user logging in
set oWshNet = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
sUser = oWshNet.Username

' Run Aplication if user is user1

if oWshnet.Username = "user1" Then
  do
    shell.exec "C:\Program Files\Canon\MP Navigator EX 4.0\mpnex40.exe",0,true
  loop
Else
  shell.run "C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe"
end if
```

I have changed to a new application and now find that it will only run the application using `shell.exec`. `shell.run` causes a path not found error. Using `shell.exec` without the loop would not normally be a problem but as I require a loop which constantly rechecks for the exit of the application, I can't seem to use shell.exec with the `,0,true` parameter.

Any ideas how I can get round this?

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method. [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) doesn't support additional arguments, and particularly doesn't support waiting for the executed program to return.

The reason why you got the "path not found" error is because your path contains spaces. You need to put double quotes around the path (inside the double quoted string) so that the whole path is recognized as one single token instead of multiple tokens `C:\Program`, `Files\Canon\MP`, aso.

Nested double quotes can be added for instance like this (doubling the double quotes escapes them inside a string):

```vb
shell.Run """C:\Program Files\Canon\MP Navigator EX 4.0\mpnex40.exe""", 0, True
```

or by using a quoting function (which is the more versatile approach):

```vb
Function qq(str) : qq = """" & str & """" : End Function
...
shell.Run qq("C:\Program Files\Canon\MP Navigator EX 4.0\mpnex40.exe"), 0, True
```